# query not returning results when using positional parameters

Tags: grails, hql

I have the following query:

```
def currentUser = User.find('from User where enabled = (:a) 
AND ( emailAddress = (:e) OR altEmailAddress like (:e) )', 
[a: _enabled, e: _email.toLowerCase()])
```

I know there is data in the tables which should be returned, it doesn't seem to return any results. Is there anything wrong with the way I'm doing a Like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use '%' before and after the value. In your case:

```
def currentUser = User.find('from User where enabled = (:a) AND ( emailAddress = (:e) OR        altEmailAddress like (:e) )', [a: _enabled, e: '%' + _email.toLowerCase() + '%'])
```

Comment: like %(:e)%  doesn't work. I had tried that before. It throws a parser error. Correct way is to actually have the % before and after the value. Even I thought that you would have to do it the way you did it but it didn't work. The second response is the right way to do it.

Comment: Ok. Editing. +1 for testing both.

Answer (score 0):

For your like portion, you want to add a `'%'` (or similar operator) somewhere in the email address, e.g. `"foo%@bar.com"`. Without one of these operators the sql will be looking for an exact match.